# Pandas dataframe query() throws error when dataframe size is more than 100 rows

Tags: python, pandas

**Code snippet 1**

```
import pandas as pd  
df = pd.read_csv("filename.txt", sep='\t', header = 0, names = ['E', 'S', 'D'])  
Result = df.query(df.E.head(**n=100**) == 0)
```

Code Snippet `1` works as expected and returns a `dataframe` with `df.E` value equal to `0`.
But,

**Code Snippet 2**

```
import pandas as pd  
df = pd.read_csv("filename.txt", sep='\t', header = 0, names = ['E', 'S', 'D'])  
Result = df.query(df.E.head(**n=101**) == 0)
```

Code Snippet 2 does not work and throws error as

> ```
> "SyntaxError: ('invalid syntax', ('<unknown>', 1, 602, '[True ,True
> ,True ,True ,True ,True ,True ,True ,True ,True ,True ,True ,True
> ,True ,True ,True ,... ,True ,True ,True ,True ,True ,True ,True ,True
> ,True ,True ,True ,True ,True ,True ,True ,...]\n'))"
> ```

Please note that only change between 2 sets of code is `n=100` and `n=101`.

The error is still present with `.head(n=101)` removed. Have tried for many values greater than `100`, throws same error.

Comment: Why are you using `query` that way?  You're supposed to pass a string, not an actual condition.  See [the documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html).

Comment: Why are the `**` there? Is that a typo?

Comment: @BrenBarn actual query is df.query(df.E == dfEgounique[eachEgo]). If i change it to df.query('df.E == dfEgounique[eachEgo]'), throws error as "NotImplementedError".

Comment: @Paul ** was added when the question was edited. Will remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

df.query accepts a string query. you are not passing valid python (it accepts a slight superset of python actually). so I wouldn't expect either of your code snippets to work at all, hence the SyntaxError.

Straight out of the doc-string

```
Parameters
----------
expr : string
    The query string to evaluate.  You can refer to variables
    in the environment by prefixing them with an '@' character like
    ``@a + b``.


In [14]: pd.set_option('max_rows',10)

In [15]: np.random.seed(1234)

In [16]: df = DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10,size=100).reshape(-1,1),columns=list('a'))

In [17]: df
Out[17]: 
    a
0   3
1   6
2   5
3   4
4   8
.. ..
95  9
96  2
97  9
98  1
99  3

[100 rows x 1 columns]

In [18]: df.query('a==3')
Out[18]: 
    a
0   3
21  3
26  3
28  3
30  3
32  3
51  3
60  3
99  3

In [19]: var = 3

In [20]: df.query('a==@var')
Out[20]: 
    a
0   3
21  3
26  3
28  3
30  3
32  3
51  3
60  3
99  3
```

Comment: Thanks Jeff. df.query('e==0') works. Further, i want to compare it with a variable instead of 0, like df.query('e==var').

Comment: Thanks. I had been trying df(df.e==var) instead of df[df.e==var]. Silly mistake. Out of curiosity, i do wonder, how my first snippet of code works, if the syntax is wrong.

Comment: with the information you have provided it is impossible to tell what var is (and show df.info() and pd.show_versions()

Comment: version = '0.15.0'
short_version = '0.15.0'  
var contains int variable